# Puppeteer - Cannot Target Checkbox on Hotel Website

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Problem**: Using Puppeteer, I cannot click `Available Hotels` check-box in hotel website (https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/hotels/chicago-il-usa?brand_id=HR&checkInDate=10/31/2023&checkOutDate=11/5/2023&useWRPoints=false&children=0&adults=3&rooms=2&loc=ChIJ7cv00DwsDogRAMDACa2m4K8&sessionId=1694533511).

[image: wyndham ss]

I tried the following below but they all didn't work for clicking "Available Hotels" check-box.

**Entire code:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const constants = require('./wyndham_constants.js');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

// * Main Function
let browser;
async function wyndhamScan() {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
    });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
    await page.setUserAgent(ua);
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1065, height: 10700 });

    // Go to the URL website
    await page.goto('https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/wyndham', { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

    // Enter destination
    await page.type('[name="destination"]', 'Chicago, IL, USA' );
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

    // Click Search button
    await page.click('.search-btn.btn-primary');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);


    // ------------------------------------------ Re-directed to Results page ----------------------------------------
    
    // Click "Available Hotels"
    // ! WIP - below does not work
    // await page.click('[class^="cmp-availability-filter"] .cmp-item-filter__span');
    // await page.click('.cmp--filter.checkbox .cmp-item-filter__span');
    // await page.click('#availabilityfilter #chk-show-avail');
    // await page.click('#availabilityfilter input[class="checkbox"]');
    // await page.click('#availabilityfilter span[class="cmp-item-filter__span"]');
    // await page.click('[class^="cmp-availability-filter"] input[class="checkbox"]');
    // await page.click('.cmp-item-filter__span');

    // Nothing clicked for this and program returned TimeoutError:
    // const checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="cmp-availability-filter"] .cmp-item-filter .checkbox');
    // checkboxs[0].click()
    
    // This returned Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement:
    // await page.click('[class^="cmp-availability-filter"] .cmp-item-filter .checkbox');
    
      const el = await page.waitForSelector("#chk-show-avail");

      try {
        await page.waitForFunction(() => {
            return !document.querySelector("#chk-show-avail").disabled;
        });
        // Clicking an element by selector
        await page.click('#chk-show-avail');
        // Wait for a specific timeout (60 seconds in this case)
        await page.waitForTimeout(60000);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await browser?.close();
    }

}

// * Call the main function
(async () => {
    console.log('Starting the Wyndham scraper program...');
    await wyndhamScan()
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        .finally(() => browser?.close());
})();
```

Comment: You need to add more details code to your question, it's hard to tell what's wrong with that with so few codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has complex behavior. The search results don't populate consistently, probably due to rate limiting, so I can't 100% verify this answer, but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.

`page.click()` is a [complex multi-step operation that moves the mouse to the coordinates of the element and issues a trusted click](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#assuming-puppeteers-api-works-like-the-native-browser-api). There are at least two confounding factors that make `page.click()` potentially the wrong tool here:

1. The checkbox starts out disabled until the search results populate, so clicking it while it's disabled won't do anything. If the hotel list never loads, the checkbox is never disabled.
2. There is a loading overlay that covers the whole screen, so clicking the element while behind this overlay will fail.

Problem 1 is a matter of waiting for the disabled attribute to be false on the element using `waitForFunction`.

If you don't need a trusted click, verify that `document.querySelector("#chk-show-avail").click()` successfully toggles the selector in the browser console, without Puppeteer. In this case, it does, so I'd use that in your Puppeteer script as well. Using the native browser click bypasses visibility, solving problem 2.

Additionally, you have a race condition when using a click that triggers a navigation. The navigation promise must be set before the click is fired, otherwise it may time out.

Putting these three steps together:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.0.2
const {setTimeout} = require("node:timers/promises");

const url = "https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/wyndham";

const navClick = async (page, sel) => {
  const nav = page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.click(sel);
  return nav;
};

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.type('[name="destination"]', "Chicago, IL, USA");
  await navClick(page, ".search-btn.btn-primary");
  const el = await page.waitForSelector("#chk-show-avail");
  await page.waitForFunction(`
    !document.querySelector("#chk-show-avail").disabled
  `);
  await el.evaluate(el => el.click());

  // not part of the logic; temporarily added so you can see
  // the box was ticked (screenshots can be hidden by modals)
  await setTimeout(60_000);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: I tried to use your code but it didn't work. And yes the search results do not populate consistently. I provided more code above.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "didn't work"? Do you get a timeout error (if so, where) and can you confirm that the feed is loading when it does fail? I ran this again this morning and it checked the box correctly--I assume the rate limiting had expired and the site loaded the feed again. Whenever the feed doesn't load, as was the case yesterday after I'd ran the script too many times, this doesn't check the box because it's disabled. Being rate limited is sort of out of scope. The added code doesn't provide much because as my post describes, multiple steps are required before the box can be checked.

Comment: It didn't click the checkbox even when the site loaded. Let me upload my entire code.

Comment: Are you running my code verbatim, or did you try to adapt it to your code prematurely, before confirming it works on its own? I've run it here 6 or 7 times this morning and it ticks the box every time the feed loads. Your updated code is complex, not a minimal example. Your `waitForNavigation()` and `click()` is incorrect--you'll want to use `Promise.all()` to avoid a race condition.

Comment: Okay I ran your minimal runnable code and it works. Let me incorporate it into my own code. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Your updated code is minimal and the main problem seems to be that navigation. I added a function `navClick` you can use whenever clicking on something that triggers a navigation.